# Angular 6 with Swiper dynamic content issue

Tags: angular, swiper.js

Angular 6 with Swiper dynamic content issue.
I wanted to rearrarange the swiper slides dynamically based on user preference

```
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <NG6componet1 ></NG6componet1>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <NG6componet2 ></NG6componet2>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <NG6componet3 ></NG6componet3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

if users prefres NG6componet2, NG6componet1, NG6componet3, i wanted to create the slides accordingly, 
I did this using AngularJS as below,

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class='swiper-wrapper'>
        <div ng-repeat="selectedview in Ctrlr.View">
            <div ui-view='{{selectedview}}' ></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='swiper-button-prev'></div>
    <div class='swiper-button-next'></div>
```

I also tried to create slide using below

```
this.swiper.appendSlide('<div class="swiper-slide"><NG6componet1></NG6componet1></div>');
this.swiper.update(true);
```

but its adding the div only not loading the component

```
<div class="swiper-slide" style="width: 431.25px; margin-right: 20px;">
  <NG6componet1></NG6componet1>
</div>
```